# Knapsack algorithm for large input

Tags: c, knapsack-problem

I have developed this knapsack algorithm based on pseudo-code found on wikipedia. It works fine for small number of items and capacity (n=6, v=2014), but it crashes for large numbers (n=5, v=123456789).

Additional problem is, that my program is tested by makefile with time limit set at 1 second.

What can i do to save time and memory?

v - Knapsack capacity 
n - Number of items 
weight[] - Weights 
value[] - Values

```
int knapSack(int v, int weight[], int value[], int n){
    int a, i, j;

    int **ks;
    ks = (int **)calloc(n+1, sizeof(int*));

    for(a = 0; a < (n+1); a++) {
        ks[a] = (int *)calloc(v+1, sizeof(int));
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j <= v; j++){
            if (weight[i-1] <= j){
                ks[i][j] = max(value[i-1] + ks[i-1][j-weight[i-1]],  ks[i-1][j]);
            } else {
                ks[i][j] = ks[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }

    int result = ks[n][v];

    for(i = 0; i < (n+1); i++) {
        free(ks[i]);
    }
    free(ks);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: how slow is it? why does it crash? how much memory does it consume?

Comment: Which algorithm on Wikipedia is this based off of?

Comment: Don't make an array of pointers. Make a single array, and access it in strides to treat it like a 2D-set.

Comment: this code needs to check the result of each call to calloc() to assure it was successful.  with large number of items, the calloc may fail, then accessing that entry, later, will cause a fault from accessing memory off of address 0.

Answer (score 1):

An array of 123456789 integer elements declared on the stack will crash many implementations of C.   Sounds like this is your problem. Did you declare your arrays inside of a function (on the stack)?

```
// on heap
static int v[123456789]={0};

// on the stack (inside a function like main() )
int foo()
{
  int v[123456789]={0};
}
```

Comment: I read all parameters through standard input. This is my main function.

`int main(){`
    `int v;`
    `scanf("%d", &v);`

    `int *weight;`
    `weight = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*40);`
    `int *value;`
    `value = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*40);`

    `int n = 0;`

    `while(2 == scanf("%d %d", &weight[n], &value[n])) {`
        `n++;`
    `}`

    `printf("%d\n", knapSack(v, weight, value, n));`
    `free(weight);`
    `free(value);`
`}`